# MCP555 manual, Yen symbol used in defining baud rate clock, what is it?

Tags: microcontroller

I am going through [this manual for the Motorola MCP555](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/user_guide/MPC555UM.pdf) micro-controller and I found an odd notation/symbol that I cannot seem to figure out what it means. The symbol appears in section 14.7.5.2 "SCK Baud Rate selection" on page 14-34.

> SCK Baud Rate = SYS^f / 2 ¥ SPBR

I cannot get the formatting correct, the term `SYS` is "to the power of" `f` but the f is on the lefthand side of `SYS` in the manual. The rest appears verbosely.

I just would like to know what the `¥` symbol means in the equation.

EDIT: Screen cap of the equation

[image]

Comment: I'd guess it's a font-rendering issue. I know Japanese locale computers replace the `/` character with the yen character in the ASCII table. I'd guess this PDF was saved with a japanese locale, or something, and it garbled the PDF somehow.

Comment: Then it would come out as `SCK = SYS / 2 / SPBR`, why wouldn't they simplify that? But you do make a very good point, I didn't think of that.

Comment: The __two__ math expressions can only be transformed into each other when `¥` means `*` (multiplication).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page 14-17 has:

[image: equation]

14-34 renders for me as:

[image: equation]

A typographical error, I'm sure.